# How to retrive data using dictionary in previous view controller which is already stored in dictionary?

Tags: swift

I am using notificationcenter to send the data to previous VController and storing multiple data in dictionary and i want to retrive data using dictionary in previous VController in swift. Below is code what i am using.

This is for swift 4.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self, 
    selector: #selector(self.methodOfReceivedNotification(tt:)), 
    name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
```

---

```
@objc func methodOfReceivedNotification(tt: Notification) {

    let dataDict = ["name" : lblName, "Midname" : lblMiddleName, "Surname" : lblSurname] as [String : AnyObject]

    if let dicto = dataDict as? [String:AnyObject]
    {
    print(dicto["name"] as! String)
    }
}
```

what i expect is just to get the data which is send from above VController.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: How you have post `NotificationCenter `?

Comment: This is my 3rd VController and NotificationCenter for post is below :-             
  @IBAction func btnEdit(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        
       // var dict = [String : AnyObject]()
      let  dict = ["name" : txtName, "Midname" : txtMidname, "Surname" : txtSurname] as [String : AnyObject]
        
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: dict)
        
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

Comment: Update your question